# Изменения яркости цвета (RGB, HSV, ITU BT.709)

Tags: математика, color

Стандарт `ITU BT.709` позволяет [вычислить](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) относительную — видимую — яркость цвета. Пространство HSV, в свою очередь, предоставляет возможность изменять абсолютное значение яркости. Появился вопрос, как связать эти величины. Скажем, в пространстве HSV яркость цвета `x` равна 90%, тогда как по формуле относительной яркости — 70%. Как рассчитать величину изменения яркости в пространстве HSV, чтобы относительная яркость, скажем, уменьшилась до 60%?

Смог дойти лишь до банального варианта — перебор, но хочется найти более эффективное решение.

Comment: Ну формула для вычисления относительной яркости из RGB есть. Весь вопрос есть ли формула для вычисления HSV из RGB и тогда может можно будет сообразить.

Comment: Да, конечно, есть. RGB свободно преобразуется в HSV. Однако у меня все еще довольно слабое представление, как лучше все это провернуть.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Max, min и mod что-то линейно не очень преобразуются, да